# How does "Yield None" work in an example from Python Cookbook, 2nd Edition?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, signals, python-multithreading

I was reviewing sample code in [Python Cookbook, 2nd Edition](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-cookbook-2nd/0596007973/) (section 9.8).

I'm not fluent in Python anymore -- took a break for many years.

I was interested in micro threading which this is an example of.

When reading the code I'm not able to make head or tail out of how "Yield None" works.

If I understand it -- it causes the variables of the function to be saved onto the stack so the function's state can be restored at a subsequent call.

This seems too magical for the snippet of code written -- would appreciate any help thanks.

NOTE: I couldn't get it to run

```
import signal
# credit: original idea was based on an article by David Mertz
# http://gnosis.cx/publish/programming/charming_python_b7.txt
# some example 'microthread' generators
def empty(name):
    """ This is an empty task for demonstration purposes. """
    while True:
        print ("<empty process>", name)
        yield None
def terminating(name, maxn):
    """ This is a counting task for demonstration purposes. """
    for i in xrange(maxn):
        print ("Here %s, %s out of %s" % (name, i, maxn))
        yield None
    print ("Done with %s, bailing out after %s times" % (name, maxn))
def delay(duration=0.8):
    """ Do nothing at all for 'duration' seconds. """
    import time
    while True:
        print ("<sleep %d>" % duration)
        time.sleep(duration)
        yield None
class GenericScheduler(object):
    def __init__(self, threads, stop_asap=False):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.shutdownHandler)
        self.shutdownRequest = False
        self.threads = threads
        self.stop_asap = stop_asap
    def shutdownHandler(self, n, frame):
        """ Initiate a request to shutdown cleanly on SIGINT."""
        print ("Request to shut down.")
        self.shutdownRequest = True
    def schedule(self):
        def noop( ):
            while True: yield None
        n = len(self.threads)
        while True:
            for i, thread in enumerate(self.threads):
                try: thread.next( )
                except StopIteration:
                    if self.stop_asap: return
                    n -= 1
                    if n==0: return
                    self.threads[i] = noop( )
                if self.shutdownRequest:
                    return
if __name__== "__main__":
    s = GenericScheduler([ empty('boo'), delay( ), empty('foo'),
                           terminating('fie', 5), delay(0.5),
                        ], stop_asap=True)
    s.schedule( )
    s = GenericScheduler([ empty('boo'), delay( ), empty('foo'),
                           terminating('fie', 5), delay(0.5),
                        ], stop_asap=False)
    s.schedule( )
```

Comment: `yield None`, or simply `yield`, works just like yielding any object, but that object is `None`. I suppose the real question here is how yield itself works: see e.g. https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators. It is indeed magic, implemented by the interpreter, and to some degree it does exactly what you describe. Nifty little code, btw, glad I saw it ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly I think this snippet is overly complex to grasp the concept.
`yield None` is no different from `yield 1` or `yield any_other_value`

When python encounters **yield** in the function code it would convert this function into a special-purpose object that behaves differently from regular functions. On every `yield` it indeeds returns the value and saves the current state. See my code sample with some debugging info (tested on `python 2.7`, may not work on python 3.x), hope it would be helpful

```
def gen():
    yield 1
    yield
    yield 2

g = gen()
print('what is a generator')
print(type(g))
print('generator contents')
print(dir(g))
print('generator gi_frame object')
print(dir(g.gi_frame))
print('code line')
print(g.gi_frame.f_lineno)

print('step 1')
print(next(g))

print('generator state after step 1')
print(g.gi_frame.f_lineno)

print('step 2')
print(next(g))

print('generate state after step 2');
print(g.gi_frame.f_lineno)


print('last step')
print(next(g))
print(g.gi_frame.f_lineno)

print('nothing left')
try:
    print(next(g))
except StopIteration as e:
    print('got StopIteration')

print(g.gi_frame)
```

output:

```
what is a generator
<type 'generator'>
generator contents
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__name__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'close', 'gi_code', 'gi_frame', 'gi_running', 'next', 'send', 'throw']
generator gi_frame object
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'f_back', 'f_builtins', 'f_code', 'f_exc_traceback', 'f_exc_type', 'f_exc_value', 'f_globals', 'f_lasti', 'f_lineno', 'f_locals', 'f_restricted', 'f_trace']
code line
1
step 1
1
generator state after step 1
2
step 2
None
generate state after step 2
3
last step
2
4
nothing left
got StopIteration
None
```